# how to avoid overwriting when inserting todolist task list

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need insert a list of tasks ( foods),
when I insert one by one all work correctly but when I insert a function that includes the 3 functions it is overwritten.

Thank you very much for your help guys.

function add Rice

```
const addRice = () => {
    /* const arrRecipe = ["rice","chicken breast", "oil"] */


    let itemRecipe = "rice";

    let index = foodDatabase.findIndex((item) => item.name === itemRecipe);

    arrFoods.unshift({
      food_id: foodDatabase[index].food_id,
      name: itemRecipe,
      type: foodDatabase[index].type,
      weight_int: foodDatabase[index].weight_int,
      prot: foodDatabase[index].prot,
      lip: foodDatabase[index].lip,
      hc: foodDatabase[index].hc,
      img_link: foodDatabase[index].img_link,
      n_int_card: foodDatabase[index].n_int_card,
      foodWeight: 0,
      idUnique: uuid(),
    });

    addFoodWeight();

    /////
    const itemAdd = {
      idUnique: arrFoods[0].idUnique,
      name: arrFoods[0].name,
      foodWeight: arrFoods[0].foodWeight,
      type: arrFoods[0].type,
      img_link: arrFoods[0].img_link,
    };

    const requestColumnId = Object.entries(columns).find(
      (i) => i[1].name === "Breakfast"
    )[0];

    const column = columns[requestColumnId];

    addFoodWeight();

    setColumns({
      ...columns,
      [requestColumnId]: {
        ...column,
        items: [...column.items, itemAdd],
      },
    });
    
  };
```

functions addRecipes (functions for rice, chicken and oil they are the same)

```
const addRecipes = () => {
    addRice();
    addChicken();
    addOil();
  };
```

one by one work correctly:
[image]

Functions addRecipes, function that includes the 3 functions it is overwritten.: [image]

Comment: Setting state is asynchronous; `...columns` will have whatever its initial value is, not what's in there after the (async) state setting resolution is complete.

Comment: Thank you I appreciate all the information that can guide me how to solve it.

Comment: Build an object with all three (recipes? ingredients?) in it and merge that with the state. Or if it's a complete state replacement just set state with all three objects.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try to implement your solution.

Comment: Thank you very much Dave Newton, I was able to implement your solution successfully, I wish you an excellent day.

Comment: Glad you worked it out!

Answer (score 0):

Try to await the functions and make your addRecipes async like so:

```
const addRecipes = async () => {
  await addRice();
  await addChicken();
  await addOil();
};
```

Comment: @MaxM besides that the function doesn't return anything awaitable, setting state doesn't return a promise anyway.